# strange behaviour - serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, dojo

i have this code:

```
var sizes = ["1/9","1/8","1/7","1/6","1/5","1/4","1/3","1/2","1/1","2/1","3/1","4/1","5/1","6/1","7/1","8/1","9/1"];

            var slider = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
                value:8,
                name:"value"+[i],
                slideDuration:0,
                onChange:function(val){ 
                    dojo.byId('value'+[i]).value = sizes[val];
                    },
                minimum:0,
                maximum:sizes.length-1,
                discreteValues:sizes.length,
                intermediateChanges:"true",
            },node);
```

now, when i made:

```
 $("#custom").submit(function() {
        var formdata = $("#custom").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data) {
}
});
```

For example, if i choose the value 1/8 it is sent as 1, or 9/1 as 16.

What i want is  send the fraction value, that is showed in the input box, but as i said, not sent to the insert.php

Any idea ? thanks

Comment: try `var sizes = ["1\/9","1\/8","1\/7"];`

Comment: @3nigma: I don't that that will solve the problem. `/` doesn't usually need to be escaped. From OP's description, if "1/8" is sent as 1 and "9/1" as 16, it sounds to me that array index is sent instead.

Comment: @darioo you are right i didn't read the `9/1` as 16 part ...

Comment: Maybe you should use .serialize() instead of serializeArray().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning during the init of the slider an `<input type="hidden" name="input0" ... />` will be created.
After using the slider this `input` get the current slider value (a number between `0` and `sizes.length - 1`). The `onChange` sets an other html input tag with the value from the array called `sizes`.
While submitting the `serializeArray()` takes the values of all input fields which have a `name` attribute.
In my [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dsFWw/) I gave the input field that will be filled at the onChange a `name` attribute, so the serialization takes both values.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="custom">
    <div id="slider0"></div>
    <input type="text" id="value0" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" name="value0" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```